Unable to get property subsituted in Spring camelContext
I am upgrading my application from Spring 4 to Spring 6.
I have a beans.xml defintion
    <camelContext id="camelContext" xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
        <route>
            <from uri="activemq:queue:${spring.my.activemq.queue}"/>
            <to uri="direct:myRemoteServiceImpl" />
            <transacted ref="PROPAGATION_REQUIRED"/>
        </route>
    </camelContext>


But in activemq UI, I am seeing the queue name as ${spring.my.activemq.queue} without reading the value from properties file.
The properties bean is as follows
    <bean id="urlPropertyConfigurer" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <property name="properties">
            <ref bean="URLProperties"/>
        </property>
        <property name="placeholderPrefix">
        <value>${spring.</value>
        </property>
    </bean>

